# Schedule a Task which runs 2 times a day

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, delete-file, windows-task-scheduler

I want to develop a tool which can delete all files of a folder 2 times a day - at 8:30 in morning and night.
It should only delete all files permanently but not the folder.

My deletion code is working fine but I am having problem with scheduling. I have no idea how to write a scheduler code. Can anyone help me with the right code to schedule it?

```
public class Delete 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        try
        { 
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dekstop\\Dummy")); 
//I want to delete all Files not the Folder
        } 
        catch(NoSuchFileException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("No such file/directory exists"); 
        } 
        catch(DirectoryNotEmptyException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Directory is not empty."); 
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Invalid permissions."); 
        } 

        System.out.println("Deletion successful."); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: why not use scheduler available at OS level, rather than writing your own? OR may be use use frameworks like Quartz.

Comment: I want to make it for my project so can't use OS schedulers....I am not familiar with Quartz so can you tell me more about it??

Comment: What if your app actually throws an error, and completely stops, along with the scheduler? That's where the OS scheduler would help - it will always trigger while the system is on

Comment: @cricket_007 can you tell me how to use OS scheduler?? I have never used it before...Thanks :)

Comment: The answers given below are poor. In particular you should not use the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class. Find the good answers in the linked original question. And next time please remember to search before posting a question. You typically find the good answers faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

**You could use Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period) method**

setting first time to in the morning (any time)  and the setting the period to 12-hours will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

go further with this [Original post](https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring)

```
public class ExecuteTimer {
  public static void main(String[] args){
       MyTimer te1=new MyTimer("My_Task1");
       MyTimer te2=new MyTimer("My_Task2");
      Timer t=new Timer();
      t.scheduleAtFixedRate(te1, 0,5*1000);
      t.scheduleAtFixedRate(te2, 0,1000);
   }
}
```

MyTimer.class

```
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask{
private String timername ;
public MyTimer(String n){
  this.timername=n;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+name+" the task has executed successfully "+ new Date());
    if("Task1".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
      try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have one doubt with the code so I have to create the TimerTask class?

Comment: yes its according to your problem .its good to go with separate class

Comment: Alright! Thanks buddy :)

Comment: It's showing me an error:  no suitable method Found for schedule

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/schedulers-in-java-and-spring go with this